# Output link when "deploying functions" for Firebase looks nothing like the github example

Tags: node.js, firebase, actions-on-google

quick question.

I've been going through the google actions tutorials and sdk and quickly went through their github located at:
https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-webhook-template-nodejs

I followed the steps to initialize my firebase client and put in the addMessage and makeUppercase functions.  Per the next step I did a firebase deploy --only functions, but this is where it gets weird.

In the sdk read.me it says it should output a link that looks similar to:
https://${REGION}-${PROJECT}.cloudfunctions.net/yourAction

However the link that terminal spit out for me was a link to my function "console" and the link looked like:
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/"my project name"/overview

I'm curious where I went wrong here as I simply copy and pasted the functions step by step and then deployed as they said.

Is this just how firebase returns the functions now?  Maybe there was an update since the node.js sdk was published the other month?  I'm worried that this outputted link is not the correct one for my webhooke in dialogflow.  When I go to my console link, I can't find anywhere that gives me a link for a webhook within that dashboard so I'm a bit confused here

EDIT: So I dug deeper in their resource page, it's telling me it should output both my Project Console link as it did above as well as the function link.  The function link is not being shown, which is leading to my confusion.  Any idea as to why the function link is not being created?

Comment: I went and deleted everything and tried again, now the function url is showing when I deployed my functions.  I think what had happened before is I had ran an npm init on my folder out of habit before doing my firebase stuff, and when using firebase functions it will build the node dependencies for you as part of the process. I think running this early npm init screwed something up and was causing my firebase commands to act weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase command line tool has changed something recently, so it only reports that URL the first time a function gets deployed. Or something like that.

The canonical way to get the URL for your function is to

1. Go to the Firebase Console (https://console.firebase.google.com/)
2. Login and select your project, if necessary.
3. Click on the "Functions" menu item on the left, which may be grouped under the "Develop" section.

[image]

4. In the center area, you'll see the function you have deployed for that project, along with the URL for it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I went and deleted everything and tried again, now the function url is showing when I deployed my functions. I think what had happened before is I had ran an npm init on my folder out of habit before doing my firebase stuff, and when using firebase functions it will build the node dependencies for you as part of the process. I think running this early npm init screwed something up and was causing my firebase commands to act weird.